# mysql is scanning table despite index

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following mysql query that I think should be faster. The database table has 1 million records and the query table 3.5 seconds

```
set @numberofdayssinceexpiration = 1; 
set @today  = DATE(now());
set @start_position =  (@pagenumber-1)* @pagesize;

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ad.id,
               title,
               description,
               startson,
               expireson,
               ad.appuserid UserId,
               user.email   UserName,
               ExpiredCount.totalcount
        FROM   advertisement ad
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT servicetypeid,
                                  Count(*) AS TotalCount
                           FROM   advertisement
                           WHERE  Datediff(@today,expireson) =
                                  @numberofdayssinceexpiration
                                  AND sendreminderafterexpiration = 1
                           GROUP  BY servicetypeid) AS ExpiredCount
                       ON ExpiredCount.servicetypeid = ad.servicetypeid
               LEFT JOIN aspnetusers user
                       ON user.id = ad.appuserid
        WHERE  Datediff(@today,expireson) = @numberofdayssinceexpiration
               AND sendreminderafterexpiration = 1
        ORDER  BY ad.id) AS expiredAds
LIMIT 20 offset 1;
```

Here's the execution plan:

[image]

Here are the indexes defined on the table:

[image]

I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when you don't need it, it's generally slower than `INNER JOIN`. Since the subquery always has the same `servicetypeid` as the main table, you don't need `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` can't be indexed. Use `WHERE expireson = @today - INTERVAL @numberofdayssinceexpiration DAY`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested Bamar and Wow, that was lightning fast! 0 seconds!. Thank you so much

Comment: General rule: if a column is used in a function, it probably won't be indexed. You have to compare the column with something.

Comment: Functions in the `WHERE` clause, such as `DATEDIFF`, among others, makes the query [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), which kills the benefit of an index, because _every row_ needs to be checked with the function.

Comment: WHERE Datediff()=...
mysql can't know where to start.Then he will scan the whole table to try every possibility

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to point out some problems.  Then I will get into your Question.

- `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 1` gives you 20 rows starting with the second row.
- The lack of an `ORDER BY` in the outer query *may* lead to an unpredictable ordering.  In particular, the Limit and Offset can pick whatever they want.  New versions will actually throw away the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.
- `DATEDIFF`, being a function, makes that part of the `WHERE` not 'sargeable'.  That is it can't use an `INDEX`.  The usual way (which is sargeable) to compare dates is (assuming `expireson` is of datatype `DATE`):

  ```
    WHERE expireson >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```
- Please qualify each column name.  With that, I may be able to advise on optimal indexes.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so that we can see what column(s) are in each index.